strong convergence and unitary evolution in Hilbert space
Consider a family of operators $A(t)$ in Hilbert space. It is known that $A(t) \to 0$, $t \to \infty$ in the strong operator topology. Consider the self-adjoint operator $H$ with purely absolutely continuous spectrum and the unitary group $i^{itH}$ generated by it. Is it true that for any $f, g$
$$
(e^{-itH} f, A(t) e^{-itH} g) \to 0 ?
$$
I know that for example $e^{-itH} g$ weakly converge to zero, but I don't know how to apply this fact to this problem.
Probably, I found solution. Due to spectral theorem we get
$$
(e^{-ith}f, A(t) e^{-ith} g) = \int_{R} e^{-i t \lambda} d (e^{-ith} f, A(t) P_{\lambda} g),
$$
where $P_{\lambda}$ is spectral measurement. And let apply dominated convergence theorem.

By the definition of SOP we have $\Vert A(t)x\Vert \to 0$ for all $x$....

@lcv, Yes, I know. But for fixed $x$, $| A(t)x | \to 0$. In this case $x(t) = e^{-itH}g$ and isn't fixed.

Why you say $x(t)$ weakly converges to zero? You have in mind a particular operator $H$?

@lcv, this statement follows for any self-adjoint operator with purely absolutely continuous spectrum$H$ from the spectral theorem. I forgot to specify this condition for $H$ in the question, but I will fix it now.
